# New Extension Tab Zip Support Required Message

Tags: extension, php

After upgrading to PHP 7.2, now receiving this message when trying to add a new Extension

```
ZIP Support Required
You will not be able to install extensions at this time because your installation of PHP does not support ZIP archives.
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved - as of 7.2 we had to separately install the zip module (which provides the ZipArchive class within php). On Amazon Linux 2 this was the php-pecl-zip and libzip-devel packages, installed via "pecl install zip".

And restart  the php-fpm service as well as httpd restart